# Does buying a new mac also get you Lion on your Apple ID?

Tags: macos, apple-id, ilife

When you buy a new mac, the iLife apps are redeemed with App Store validation codes which means you can upgrade/install iLife 11 on your other macs. (Assuming you have fewer than the current store limit of 5 macs connected to your store Apple ID and the software requirements are met).

Does [this also apply](http://www.macworld.com/article/161396/2011/07/new_mac_lion_ilife.html) to Lion?

I would presume no since the linked MacWorld article clearly only mentions iLife. I'm mostly interested in how the App Store is working and this appears to be a new function where it's allowing a programatic access to an asset that also is being sold under the normal store terms of redemption code or direct payment.

Comment: I'm looking for an authoritative answer from someone that has bought a mac with Lion pre-installed if possible. I'm also aware of the temporary up to date program. I'm happy waiting till one with Lion pre-installed can be opened and reported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The copy of Lion you get with a new Mac is only available via the recovery partition on the hard drive and this version of the OS is tied to the hardware.

[From this MacWorld article that talks about how the version of iLife you get with a new Mac is a full Mac App Store version you can install on multiple Macs in your house](http://www.macworld.com/article/161396/2011/07/new_mac_lion_ilife.html):

> When you reinstall Lion via Lion Recovery, it seems Apple uses information about your Mac's hardware to verify that it has a license for Lion.

[Or as this summary of the MacWorld article puts it](http://www.57digital.co.uk/another-reason-to-get-a-mac-free-ilife-for-any-mac-you-own):

> Unfortunately, as Macworld points out, this trick doesn’t apply to OS X Lion itself — there’s no DVD or thumb drive included with a new Mac, which means the big cat only lives on your new Mac’s recovery partition, which appears to be tied to the hardware itself — meaning you can’t install it on your other Macs without ponying up the $29.99 from the Mac App Store.

Would be nice if you got it for your other Macs for free when you bought a new Mac, but for now it seems like it'll still cost you another $30 to bring all the Macs you own up to the current OS rev.

Comment: Awesome - Let me condense this to three sentences and see if you agree: 1. You get redemption codes for iLife only - not for Lion. 2. You have to purchase Lion on the app store to have it installed on any mac that didn't ship with Lion. 3. A short window of some macs get Lion redemption codes due to http://www.apple.com/macosx/uptodate/

Comment: @bmike: I agree 100% with what you've written. That's my understanding of the situation as well from everything I've read.

Answer (score 1):

This is second-hand information via TUAW.com, and not personal experience, but anyway, according to TUAW, the OS X license bought with a machine is tied to the hardware and not transferable.

See:

http://www.tuaw.com/2011/07/29/dear-aunt-tuaw-if-i-sell-my-old-mac-does-lion-go-with-it/

So the answer to your question would be "no".

Comment: Thanks for that link. The redemption codes shipping with the mac imply to me that iLife belongs to your account - not the hardware. If they also send a Lion redemption code but tie it to one machine (only or just one at a time) that would be new ground for the App Store in terms of licensing.