# If I buy a Mac that comes with Lion, can I install it on my old Macs too?

Tags: macos, mac, mac-appstore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does buying a new mac also get you Lion on your Apple ID?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19271/does-buying-a-new-mac-also-get-you-lion-on-your-apple-id)

If I buy a new Mac with OS X Lion, will I then be able to update my old computers to Lion via the Mac App Store without charge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No - macs ship with one license to Lion - for that mac.

If you buy an upgrade outright, that applies to all your macs.